# How to change the cell back ground color using IIF EVAL

Tags: asp.net, gridview, eval

How can I change the background color of a GridView cell using IIF and EVAL?

I thought it would be something like this, but it does not seem to work.

```
<asp:TextBox 
   ID="textbox1" 
   runat="server" 
   Text='<%# Eval("Field1") %>' 
   Width="100px" 
   visible="false" 
   BackColor='<%# IIF(Eval("Field1")>5,"Red","Blue") %>'>
</asp:TextBox>
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace Red and Blue string constant with color objects.

```
BackColor='<%# IIF(Eval("Field1")>5,System.Drawing.Color.Red,System.Drawing.Color.Blue) %>'>
```

Or

```
BackColor='<%# IIF(Integer.Parse(Eval("Field1").ToString())>5,System.Drawing.Color.Red,System.Drawing.Color.Blue) %>'>
```